# Implement Search by Keyword on Youtube

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I've been struggling on implementing SearchByKeyword for Youtube as I find it hard to relate the Java language used in almost all documentation. I think

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Search.java

is the most relevant to what I want but I can't get it to work at all. My confusion:

How do I engage this Search class? For example on a button click? I'm not sure where is the constructor that I can call for and put in the keywords that I want to search for.
For example: In line 90 of the code

```
String queryTerm = getInputQuery();
```

will call
    private static String getInputQuery() throws IOException {

```
    String inputQuery = "";

    System.out.print("Please enter a search term: ");
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

    if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
        // Use the string "YouTube Developers Live" as a default.
        inputQuery = "YouTube Developers Live";
    }
    return inputQuery;
}
```

I want to get my keywords through `EditText.getText().toString()` and engaging the search by clicking on a `Button`. Which will return to me a list of results that I can use an `ArrayAdapter` to be viewed.

How do I do so? Thanks in advance for any aid. I have been searching for guidance for days with no result, there are documentations but I can't translate them into Android. Please help.

Comment: Hello, I have a query code with youtube api, it is not the way you are trying to do, but I can share if you have interest.

Comment: Any help is help! Sure thing I'll try to learn what I can

Answer (score 1):

Firstly that's your endPoint = https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=YOURKEYFORSEARCH&type=video&key=YOURAPIKEY;

`private void yourQueryToYoutubeAPI(final String keyWord)` {

```
    final  String yourApiKEY = "yourApiKey";
    final String endPoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="+ keyWord+"&type=video&key=" + yourApiKEY;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Object jsonResponse = null;

            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

                request.setURI(new URI(endPoint));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                jsonResponse = gson.fromJson(reader, HashMap.class);

                //jsonRespose contains your query result you can see result with log for example
                Log.i("jsonResponse", "jsonResponse: " + jsonResponse.toString());

                content.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }).start();
}`
```

this will give you an early idea of ​​how to use api, do tests and more tests.

you can find more information on which camps are retrievable here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en

***extra information:***
at each query for the search field, it costs 100.
you have an initial limit of 1,000,000 you can contact youtube when this limit is close to being reached but I am not sure if you will have to pay for it.

you can find more about the quota limit here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quota. I never knew until now. I got an error for the code, 'The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint.' I've checked my package name and SHA1 certificate, which are correct. I've created another API key and set the restrictions to none and it worked. Thanks, but any idea how to get it to work with restrictions?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm using an unrestricted api key too!